# get "outertext" HTML with simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Im using simple html dom to scrape a news website. After a long search for fixing reative URls to absolute I finaly was able to get it right like this:

```
$url = 'http://www.nu.nl';

    $html = file_get_html($url);
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
        echo url_to_absolute($url, $element->href), "<br />";
    }
```

The problem now is that this outputs the href as plain text. There are built in functions in simple html dom like "outertext", "innertext" and so on to get the html as plain html. How do I use this functions in the code above? How do I (for instance ) echo the complete page `echo $html` and include the code above to fix the URls?

Comment: nm, just was curious if you was building some proxy for `nu.nl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but I think you can do something like

```
$url = 'http://www.nu.nl';

$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    $element->href = url_to_absolute($url, $element->href);
}
echo $html->save();
```

Since `$element` is a reference (I'm assuming) and `$html->save()` will recreate it from the DOM tree it will give the modified source

Comment: Thank you very much:) Yes Im building a proxy. By the way do you think I can do this for images `foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    $element->src = url_to_absolute($url, $element->src);
}` I put this code underneath yours and it worked. Is this the best way to write it or is there a better(more efficient) way..?

Comment: I think its the most _elegant_ way, but also the most heaviest and slowest way. if you really want performance I think you have to stick with regex. should make a benchmark for that tho, I will make one if I have some spare time

Comment: No, html should never be parsed with regex. Performance should never be a consideration.

Comment: @pguardiario Its not about parsing the HTML with regex, that would be plain dirty, but more about replacing the links in the source with regex

Comment: Hmm, you probably shouldn't be doing that either. Unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: @pguardiario Nice blog you got:) Thanks for sharing your knowledge